# Back Button Disappear when view open from remote push notification

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-push-notifications

I used remote push notification in my app, when app are closed and notification appear on iPhone and user opened it, app opened on specified view, in normal this view have back button to viewcontrolA, but back button not fun when open from notification, I need help to solve it.[image: normal view when open from app]
[image: view when opened from remote push notification]

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:

```
     if (launchOptions != nil)
        {
            NSDictionary* dictionary1 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsRemoteNotificationKey];
            NSDictionary* dictionary2 = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
            if (dictionary1 != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Launched from push notification: %@", dictionary1);
                double delayInSeconds = 7;
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    //   [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary1 updateUI:NO];
                });

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];
            UIStoryboard *story=[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainiPad" bundle:nil];
            MFSideMenuContainerViewController *controller=(MFSideMenuContainerViewController*)self.window.rootViewController;
            UINavigationController *mainVC=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:DetailsSearchNav];
            [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
            [controller.shadow setOpacity:0.75f];
            [controller setCenterViewController:mainVC];
            UIViewController *leftController=[story instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LeftSideViewController"];
            [controller setRightMenuViewController:leftController];
            [controller setLeftMenuViewController:nil];
            }

            if (dictionary2 != nil)
            {
                NSLog(@"Launched from dictionary2dictionary2dictionary2 notification: %@", dictionary2);
                double delayInSeconds = 7;
                dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
                dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
                    // [self addMessageFromRemoteNotification:dictionary2 updateUI:NO];
                });
            }

        }
```

Comment: I think are you presented the viewcontrller

Comment: I launched it from app delegate

Comment: can you show your code

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik I added it

Comment: not this one bro , add your remote notification delegate methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes because you are setting **Property Details** `ViewController` as the root controller of `UINavigationController`. Hence it doesn't know the previous `ViewController` to navigate.

Comment: Without rootviewController how to push viewController from AppDelegate?

Answer (score 3):

Back button only shows when there is a view to go back in navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

As a `UINavigationController` hierarchy you that our screen backbutton show by default because that navigate from Listing Page. While you are come this `viewcontroler` from `Notification` at that time Property Detauls view becomea  `Rootviewcontrollers`. so following is Logic.

- Set a back button in Details View controller programmatically. and on their event you just need to check is that `viewcontroler` is open from pushed `viewcontroler` or `rootviewcontroller` and make a code as per condition.
- If The openviewcontroller as a rootviewcontrolelr then on back click you need to add new Rootviewcontroller using window object.
- Else that back working parfect pop to viewcontroller.

Comment: Perfect one @Nitin Gohel